# Writing hierarchical xml from DataSet

Tags: xml, vb.net, dataset

I have a `DataSet` which looks something like shown below.

```
Level 1 Level 2     Value
Group1  Parameter1  Value1
        Parameter2  Value2
Group2  Parameter3  Value3
        Parameter4  Value4
```

When I write this to xml, it should like something as below:

```
<Group1>
   <Parameter1>
   <Value> Value1 </Value>
   </Parameter1>
   <Parameter2>
   <Value> Value2 </Value>
   </Parameter2>
</Group1>
<Group2>
   <Parameter3>
   <Value> Value2 </Value>
   </Parameter3>
   <Parameter4>
   <Value> Value4 </Value>
   </Parameter4>
</Group2>`
```

Using command `dataset.writexml(filename)` doesnot serve this purpose.
Can anybody tell me how to do this? 
Should I include separate tables for `Group1` and `Group2` in dataset?
Do I need to write xml schema for this? If yes, can anybody give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DataSet.GetXml` which returns the XML representation of the data stored in the `DataSet`

```
Dim result As String = ds.GetXml
Console.WriteLine(result)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. Using method you have suggested, I can get xml representation, but what if I want to change it. How to change this representation?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible because the datatable has just one possible representation as XML (Probably I'm speaking from ignorance) because it follows a hierarchical order when building the XML. The first node is the name of your table. You can change this by setting a name on your DataSet.

`Dim ds As New DataSet("Groups")` <-- plural.

The inner node is the record. You can change this by specifying the name when you fill the adapter.

`adapter.Fill(ds, "Group")` <-- singular